# Oracle/ External file xyz not found

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Already went through numerous sites/posts, but just couldn't find any working solution.

I'm using Oracle 11g R2 XE on Windows and trying to create external table to load the data.

1. Data file has only one line with no header:

   AAA,BBB
2. Login to the "SYSTEM" schema/user
3. Creating a directory like the below one:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY rawdata
   AS 'C:\...\RAW_DATA'
   ;
   ```
4. Creating external table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE rawdata_import  
   ( col1        VARCHAR2(3)  
   , col2        VARCHAR2(3))  
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL  
   ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER  
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY rawdata  
       ACCESS PARAMETERS  
       ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE  
         NOBADFILE   
         NODISCARDFILE   
         NOLOGFILE  
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       )  
       LOCATION ('rawdata.csv'));
   ```
5. When executing simple SELECT statement:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM rawdata_import
   ;
   ```

I can see the below error.

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04040: file rawdata.csv in RAWDATA not found
```

Many thanks to anyone who can help on this one.

Rafal.

Comment: Try comparing your steps with the ones from this [Orafaq post] (http://www.orafaq.com/node/848). I think you missed the permissions steps. If that does not address the issue, another think to look into is the backslashes in the Windows path, you might need to escape these by adding another backslash before each one.

Comment: Does `rawdata.csv` actually exist in the Windows directory you specified, on the database server (not your client, if they are different), and is it accessible and readable by the Oracle O/S account? Are you creating the table as SYSTEM too - if so that isn't a good idea, grant permissions on the directory object to a normal user and create the external table under that schema instead.

Comment: @vmachan, from the point of view I was working on the "SYSTEM" schema all necessary privs are in place, and yeah... that's not what one should do, but this is just to create a logic for the future. Thanks for the link, went through this before. In terms of slashes, I tried both sides, even additional one at the end.

Comment: @Alex Poole, the file already exists, I'm doing the sfuff on my local machine. I made the whole process like 1:1 comparing to what can be found on diffrent sites. Any other idea ???

Answer (score 0):

Found out the resolution. The case was that one of the subfolders within the exact path had **diacritics**.